# Attributes are applied to ALL items instead of just current item?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, overwrite

I am using AngularJS and trying to record the unique color hues of various items. I have an array of items and an array of colors:

```
$scope.item = [
  {name:"Toy Car", colors:[]},
  {name:"Toy Boat", colors:[])
];

$scope.colors = [
  {id:"Red", intensity:256},
  {id:"Green", intensity:256},
  {id:"Blue", intensity:256}
];
```

I have an input that allows me to change the intensity of each color. When I click the APPLY button, the colors[] is copied into the items array[0].colors.

```
<input type='number' ng-model='colors[0].intensity'> //repeat for each color RGB
<button ng-click='apply()'>APPLY</button>

$scope.apply = function(){
  $scope.color_this = angular.copy($scope.colors, $scope.color_this);
  $scope.item[0].colors = angular.copy($scope.color_this, $scope.item[0].colors);
  $scope.color_this = []; // blank array to make room for the next RGB mix
};
```

This works great until I go to the next $scope.item[1].colors. When I try to set the next colors of $scope.item[1], the previous item colors get overwritten as well. That is:

```
$scope.item[0].colors === $scope.item[1].colors // evaluates to true
```

But I do not want this! I want each item to be able to keep its own unique colors. Is there something fundamentally wrong with my logic? Why do previous item colors get overwritten??

Comment: Can you share the template of item or a [mcve] ..?

Comment: Dont change $scope.apply function, ITS ANGULAR FUNCTION! :D

Comment: name your function myApply or something else

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like it's somehow related to deep copy problem of Javascript arrays.
I'll recommend to skip second parameter of angular.copy().
check out documentation here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy

Something like this...

```
$scope.apply = function(){
  $scope.color_this = angular.copy($scope.colors);
  $scope.item[0].colors = angular.copy($scope.color_this);
  $scope.color_this = []; // This line is not needed since copy will create a new array each time, so you can remove this
};
```

Just give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunetly that did not work. I will come back to this problem later as my main AGILE goals take higher priority. Thank you for your help!